# mongo db - project values into vectors

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pipeline

I want to combine values from multiple documents into single one.

original documents:

`{'a': 1,   'b': 2}`

`{'a': 100, 'b': 200}`

desired output:

`{'a': [1, 100], 'b': [2, 200]}`

Does pipeline group\project could help me with it?

Comment: Please show us your actual documents and what you have tried and the purpose of doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform your documents into an array using [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) and `$$ROOT`variable. Then you can run [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) twice in order to get single document containing all the arrays. In the last step you can run [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) with [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) to get `a,b..` as your document keys.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            data: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$data" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$data.k",
            vals: { $push: "$data.v" }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            aggregates: { $push: { k: "$_id", v: "$vals" } }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$aggregates" }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fYjp80sOkOX)